# playing sound notification for php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am try to add a sound to it as soon as new data is added to the database but when i add to the script above, it plays the audio every 1 seconds

```
var count_cases = -1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "cab_booking.php",
        success : function(response){
            if (count_cases != -1 && count_cases != response) alert('new record on i_case');
            count_cases = response;
        }
    });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior of `setInterval()`: it runs something repeatedly on the delay that you give it (in your case, `1000` or 1 second).

I think you're intending to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead of `setInterval()`.